# MySQL Full-text search using OR

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a MySQL database and i want to search using match.
I use the following query for one phrase.

```
SELECT 
    text, date, type
FROM
    `test`
WHERE
    MATCH (`TEXT`) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
;
```

But i cant find a way to search `'+word1 +word2' OR '+word3 +word4'`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
MATCH (`TEXT`) AGAINST ('(+word1 +word2) (+word3 +word4)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```